# Programmatically accessing the .NET APIs

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

Is there a way to retrieve metadata about the .NET APIs?

For example, suppose I'd like to get a list of all the [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522767.aspx) defined for `System.Windows.Documents.List`. It'd be nice to get this information in some structured format such as XML, JSON, etc. Each entry should look something like:

```
<property name="MarkerStyle" type="TextMarkerStyle" get="true" set="true"/>
```

I'd like to avoid having to screen scrape the MSDN library. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) to retrieve metadata about existing classes at runtime. The [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getproperties.aspx) method is something you could start with.

Comment: Thanks Darin! I've posted a small code example as one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0cs7xez%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and write some code to do the formatting into XML, JSON etc.

Or you can use a tool like [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Darin and Robert for the pointers to the `System.Reflection` namespace.

Here is a short program which prints out all the public properties of `List`:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace ReflectionWpfListPropertiesTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var members = typeof(List).GetMembers();

            Array.ForEach(members, info =>
                {
                    if (info.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                        Console.WriteLine(info);
                });
        }
    }
}
```